# Feature test needs to mock an API wrapper class inside a Laravel service class

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, phpunit

I have a Laravel project where I have three classes: a controller, a service and an API wrapper. Each structure is presented bellow in a simplified version. I want to write a couple of feature tests to test the implementation and I'm having trouble mocking the API wrapper class.

I tried this approach as per Laravel documentation:

```
$this->mock(PayNowAPIClient::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
    $mock->shouldReceive('pay')->once()->andReturn($mockResponse);
});
```

But I get an error saying:

> TypeError: App\Services\PayNowAPIClient::__construct(): Argument #1 ($apiKey) must be of type string, null given`

This is true because nowhere has a constructor argument been passed.

Is it even possible to mock that class and also pass a random API key to the constructor?

**PayNowController**

```
class PayNowController extends Controller
{
    protected PayNowService $payNowService;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->payNowService = app()->make(PayNowService::class, ['user' => $request->user()]);
            return $next($request);
        }
    }

    public function pay(PayNowRequest $request)
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->payNowService->handlePayment($request->validated());
            return new PaymentResource($result);
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $exception->getMessage()], 500);
        }
    }
}
```

**PayNowService**

```
class PayNowService
{
    private User $user;
    private PayNowAPIClient $client;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->client = new PayNowAPIClient($user->pay_now_api_key);
    }

    public function handlePayment(array $attributes) 
    {
        $response = $this->client->pay($attributes);

        // Some other logic goes here
    }
}
```

**PayNowAPIClient**

```
class PayNowAPIClient
{
    private string $apiKey;
    private string $baseURL = 'https://api.example.com/v1/';

    public function __construct(string $apiKey)
    {
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
    }

    public function pay(array $attributes)
    {
        return $this->makeRequest($this->baseURL . $attributes);
    }
}
```

In the `register` method of the `AppServiceProvider` I have this statement:

```
$this->app->bind(PayNowService::class, function ($app, $parameters) {
    $user = $parameters['user'] ?? \Auth::user();
    return new PayNowService($user);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I will try to help you.

You can [pass constructor's arguments](https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#constructor-arguments) to the mock, so your code can be like this:

```php
$mock = \Mockery::mock(PayNowAPIClient::class, ['stringToPassToConstructor']);

$mock->shouldReceive('pay')->once()->andReturn($mockResponse);

$this->bind(PayNowAPIClient::class, $mock);
```

See what [`$this->mock`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/971e8224d1f109e66f0de00dbe04602d5ee3a073/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithContainer.php#L61-L64) does (exactly our new code). We are literally passing `stringToPassToConstructor` so it has something, we do not care what key as we just need to pass a string and done.

This should fix your issue.

---

Let me try to add one more thing: if in the future you need to also mock `new PayNowAPIClient`, then you can do this:

```php
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->client = resolve(PayNowAPIClient::class, ['user' => $user->pay_now_api_key]);
}
```

So, that way you are telling the Container to resolve `PayNowAPIClient` and when it asks for `user` (variable in the constructor), it will pass the one found on the array, else it will try to resolve it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. Unfortunately the error persists. For some reason the  `stringToPassToConstructor` doesn't get to where it should.

Comment: Ok, my bad, managed to make it work. The parameter gets to the constructor, but it looks like it's not really mocking, it's still calling the API and I get an error that the API key is not valid.

Comment: Try this then, `$this->bind` instead of `$this->instance`. If it works, I will update the answer to reflect the working one